# Rename a Whatsapp conversation from a former employee to the new employee

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

We use WhatsApp a lot at work. We had an employee leave and now her replacement logged in and it comes up as the former employee.

How do we change it at both ends to make sure everyone knows who she is when we message?

Answer (score 1):

She can rename herself on her phone  but only the photo is propogated yo other accounts. Her name is whatever someone has named that contact.

Get her to send a message to others requesting them to rename her contact entry.